# power of a modulated signal

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

I have verified that for a pure carrier the power is 0 dBm. But when i see a qpsk/psk modulated signal the power reduces. How can i calculate how much the power has been reduced?
Is there any mathematics behind this

Comment: "when I see a modulated signal, the power reduces": That means you already know the way to calculate the power of the modulated signal. Is that right?

Comment: No I just checked on the spectrum analyzer. I observed that for a pure carrier its 0dBm. but for modulated signal level was less about -6dBm. I am not sure about the calculation behind this?

Comment: ohhh are you sure you're interpreting what you read on your SA correctly? Unless your resolution bandwidth is > modulated signal bandwidth, then reading -6dB doesn't mean the power has been reduced.

Comment: The total power of the modulated signal was 0dBM but the max level was reduced by 6dBm?

Comment: sounds about right! notice that if your display says 6dBm, that's a *power*, not a *power density*. You really need to understand that the SA shows you powers – in observation bandwidths. So, logically, modulating a carrier needs to distribute the same power on a wider bandwidth. The peak *cannot* stay the same, unless the observation bandwidth is at least as large as the modulation bandwidth. You might want to revisit what a spectrum analyzer *really* shows you!

Comment: I suspect your question has been answered, but even if it has, could you post pictures from your spectrum analyzer?  At that point then I suspect that Marcus's response could become an answer, and there will be a nice question/answer pair for future generations.

Comment: Marcus, I understand that modulating distributes the power  over the BW. So total power remains the same. But my question was is there any calculation to tell how much does the peak level reduce with the modulation?